# jQuery UI Touch Punch is not working in chrome and opera on android device

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using jQuery UI drag&drop and sortable in my website but its not working in android device browsers like chrome and opera but its working in default browser and Firefox mobile. Even I used Touch Punch plugin.

Is that issue because of browser compatible in android devices?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be browser compatibility, not all of the TouchPunch demos work on my Android 4.3 devices in Chrome or default browser, or iPad 4 for that matter.

TouchPunch does state that it is a hack so I'm avoiding it and trying to find another solution. [Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) seems to work nicely, but I don't think it is under active development.

**Update**
After writing my answer I read that the demos on TouchPunches GitHub page dont work on some mobile devices running chrome because GitHub may be serving JS as Text/Html.

Using the TouchPunch scrips locally or on a development server appears to work OK, its just the demo's on the Git Hub pages which have an issue with chrome for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with certain mobile browsers, while others worked well.  I was able to fix if by adding type="text/javascript" to my script tag as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- copy TouchPunch JQuery hack here --></script>
```

or if you have the js in an external file, be sure to add the type attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/pathtotouchpunchjsfile.js"></script>
```

(Side tip: for maximum compatibility among different browsers I use an ending script tag instead of just self-closing it)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Take a look at this fork with a fix: https://github.com/fr33kvanderwand/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Your issue with the touch-punch events is beeing discussed here: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/215

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Answer (score 0):

after the version 70 chrome does not supports touch events.So you need to replace below line,
jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js
Line 14

```
$.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document;
```

to

```
$.support.touch = 'ontouchend' in document || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
```